# How can I place a one-column-abstract in a two-column document with lyx

Tags: lyx, elsarticle

I use elsarticle template with LyX,

`(document ->settings->document class ->Elsevier )`

and I want to prepare an article in two column model.

1. **How can I place a one-column-abstract and after that two-column-section in a elsarticle template with LyX?**
2. **How can I do the same things for the image? (image one column and the section two columns).**

Thank you.

Comment: cross-posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107985/how-can-i-place-a-one-column-abstract-in-a-two-column-document-with-lyx. Please read http://latex-community.org/home/latex-community/94-etiquette/454-crossposts and think about why cross-posting without referencing the other posts can be impolite to those who would like to spend their time to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

**Two column**

`elsarticle.cls` provides various class options for different layout, ie, for onecolumn, twocolumn, specific citation styles etc. 
A very good documentation is available at [elsdoc](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0009/56844/elsdoc2.pdf).

Here, you may try either with `3p,twocolumn` or `5p,twocolumn` option. `5p` will give you more text area in the document.

In Lyx, the class options (5p,twocolumn) may be given in `Document -> Settings -> Document Class` **Custom** field.

This will provide you `twocolumn` text after the abstract section.

**Figure**

Insert your figure and right click on `float: Figure` which is shown just above the figure box. Then select `settings -> Span columns`.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer, but still don't work an error displayed " \documentclass[preprint,12pt,5p,twocolumn]{ elsarticle}
The document may only declare one class."                            i think maybe "multicol" package is missing so i will try to install and i will tested again

Comment: hi again , sorry but i still have this error "The document may only declare one class." and i didn't' figure out how to solve it

Comment: @hajerjomaa You don't have to give `\documentclass` line in `Lyx`, sorry for the confusion.  In Lyx, the class options (5p,twocolumn) may be given in Document -> Settings -> Custom field.

Comment: With regard to the `figure` span, see the original Answer.  I have edited my Answer to reflect this.

Comment: ,sorry but i didn't found what you said in lyx ,there is no "Custom field"   .if you mean Document -> Settings -> Text Layout-> Two column document . i tried but the text and the abstrct are missedup. also  no Span columns for the figure

Comment: See:   Document -> Settings -> Document Class (the very first option), then select `Custom` and add `5p,twocolumn`

Comment: @ Sunilkumar KS    thank you a lot ,it worked for the two columns perfectly, ( you have juste to  write 5p )     
,but can you help me with the figure please

Comment: @hajerjomaa  I have already included its solution in my Answer, did you check that?

Comment: hi and thank you again ,i did check and i founded but  the image don't display anymore in the pdf , i don't khnow why

Comment: You may check `Document -> LaTeX Log` to see what is happening during the PDF generation.  Ensure you are using the correct format of image.

Comment: @ Sunilkumar ok i will check thank you again for your  answer ,but please if can i ask one more, i posted a question about the corresponding author but no one answer me , if you have any idea ,can you please help me  " http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353335/corresponding-author-with-lyx

Comment: You may please check the Answer there, cheers :-)