# corresponding author with lyx

Tags: lyx, elsarticle

I use elsarticle template with LyX,

The problem is that I need the corresponding author information at the bottom of the first page.but when i use the label corresponding author ,an eroor generate

can any one tell me how can i do it with lyx please

thank you a lot

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a MWE to help us understand your problem.

Comment: For more info on a MWE in LyX, please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For corresponding author mark**

Place your cursor after the author name and give appropriate `label` by selecting:

`Insert -> Custom Insets -> CorAuthormark`

**For corresponding author text**

1. Place your cursor above Address, and select `Corresponding author` from the drop down menu which is just below `File` option.  It will generate `Corresponding author text`.
2. Then right click and select `Author Footnote Label` and give the same `label` given for `CorAuthormark`.  And add appropriate text after this.

Comment: thank a lot ,this is really kind from you ,really thank you